# Creation dataframe from several list of lists

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe

I need to build a dataframe from 10 list of list. I did it manually, but it's need a time.  What is a better way to do it?

I have tried to do it manually. It works fine (#1) 
I tried code (#2) for better perfomance, but it returns only last column.

## 1

```py
    import pandas as pd
    import numpy as np
    a1T=[([7,8,9]),([10,11,12]),([13,14,15])]
    a2T=[([1,2,3]),([5,0,2]),([3,4,5])]
    print (a1T)
    #Output[[7, 8, 9], [10, 11, 12], [13, 14, 15]]
    vis1=np.array (a1T)
    vis_1_1=vis1.T
    tmp2=np.array (a2T)
    tmp_2_1=tmp2.T
    X=np.column_stack([vis_1_1, tmp_2_1])
    dataset_all = pd.DataFrame({"Visab1":X[:,0], "Visab2":X[:,1], "Visab3":X[:,2], "Temp1":X[:,3], "Temp2":X[:,4], "Temp3":X[:,5]})
    print (dataset_all)
    Output: Visab1  Visab2  Visab3  Temp1  Temp2  Temp3
0       7      10      13      1      5      3
1       8      11      14      2      0      4
2       9      12      15      3      2      5

> Actually I have varying number of columns in dataframe (500-1500), thats why I need auto generated column names. Extra index (1, 2, 3) after name Visab_, Temp_ and so on - constant for every case.  See code below.
For better perfomance I tried

code<br>
#2
```

```
n=3 # This is varying parameter. The parameter affects the number of columns in the table. 
m=2 # This is constant for every case. here is 2, because we have "Visab", "Temp"
mlist=('Visab', 'Temp')
nlist=[range(1, n)]
for j in range (1,n):
    for i in range (1,m):
    col=i+(j-1)*n
    dataset_all=pd.DataFrame({mlist[j]+str(i):X[:, col]})
```

```
I expect output like
```

`Visab1  Visab2  Visab3  Temp1  Temp2  Temp3
0       7      10      13      1      5      3
1       8      11      14      2      0      4
2       9      12      15      3      2      5`

```
but there is not any result (only error expected an indented block)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so the number of columns n is the number of sublists in each list, right? You can measure that with len:

```
len(a1T)
#Output
3
```

I'll simplify the answer above so you don't need X and add automatic column-names creation:

```
my_lists = [a1T,a2T]
my_names = ["Visab","Temp"]

dfs=[]
for one_list,name in zip(my_lists,my_names):
  n_columns = len(one_list)
  col_names=[name+"_"+str(n) for n in range(n_columns)]
  df = pd.DataFrame(one_list).T
  df.columns = col_names
  dfs.append(df)

dataset_all = pd.concat(dfs,axis=1)

#Output
    Visab_0     Visab_1     Visab_2     Temp_0  Temp_1  Temp_2
0     7           10          13          1        5       3
1     8           11          14          2        0       4
2     9           12          15          3        2       5
```

Answer (score 0):

Now is much clearer. So you have:

```
X=np.column_stack([vis_1_1, tmp_2_1])
```

Let's create a list with the names of the columns:

```
columns_names = ["Visab1","Visab2","Visab3","Temp1","Temp2","Temp3"]
```

Now you can directly make a dataframe like this:

```
dataset_all = pd.DataFrame(X,columns=columns_names)

#Output
    Visab1  Visab2  Visab3  Temp1   Temp2   Temp3
0     7       10      13      1       5       3
1     8       11      14      2       0       4
2     9       12      15      3       2       5
```

Comment: Hello. Thank you for help. I created a simple reproducible example. I think it's clear example now.

Comment: `columns_names = ["Visab1","Visab2","Visab3","Temp1","Temp2","Temp3"]` It's not a solution, because I have a large dataset: Visab_1 to VisabN, Temp_1 to TempN, Pressure_1 to Pressure_N and so on. As I said, I need a automatic creation of column names.

Comment: So now the question is "how to generate a large list with column names?"

Comment: Alright, i think I got it. Where do you get the prefix of the names: "Viasb","Temp"... do you have a list for that? I'll post a new answer since the old one can be useful for someone anyway